# Do I have to pay taxes while being an employee as a full-time?

Tags: canada, fulltime

I am new to canada employment laws, Contractor and Employee.

Basically I have been offered a role in Canada recently as a full-time employee,

I have been offered $40 CAD hourly rate,

My question is as an employee do I have to pay my taxes from that 40$ or is my employer going to pay that, and that $40 CAD is going directly to my pocket money? No need to pay taxes

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the tax laws between you and your employer would be different from the US(assuming you are in the US)?

Comment: You mention both employee and contactor in the first line - are you actually employed directly or as a contractor its not 100% clear.

Comment: It sounds like you're a US citizen who is going to work in Canada. Are you trying to ask if you have to pay dual taxes or if you have to pay taxes between one country or another? My thought is you should talk to a tax specialist or ask your employer in Canada.

Answer (score 2):

The taxes will come out of that $40 dollars, as to how that will occur, you will need to look at your paystub.

Your employer should be taking the taxes off, but if they are not OR if they are taxing you incorrectly, when you file your taxes at the end of the year you could owe Canada Revenue Agency (CRA) money. If your employer is not taking off taxes, that will be reflected on both your paystub and the T4 they will give you at tax time. If they are not taking off tax, it will be up to you to deduct it from yourself and pay your taxes at the end of the year.

Once you file your taxes, you will receive a Notice of Assessment from CRA stating either:

1. You owe them money
2. They owe you money
3. Correct amount of taxes were paid and no one owe anyone

Taxes in Canada are based on yearly income, so if you worked at company A and made $70/h then moved to company B and are making less, you could have some problems. Company B is basing your taxes based on what they are paying you, and not taking into account how much you have already made.

Check your paystub to verify if indeed taxes are coming off.

Also remember you will have more deductions than just tax, you will also be paying into Employment Insurance (EI) and Canada Pension Plan (CPP)

Comment: Is an hourly rate always explicitly before taxes in Canada? In my locale, it's fairly common to explicitly mention whether a given rate is before or after taxes, so when a rate is mentioned without this specification one can easily ask *"Is that before or after taxes?"* without looking odd.

Comment: almost 100% of the time it is the hourly rate before taxes. It would be considered odd (but not impossible) for that to be the amount after tax. Because it is something out of the ordinary, it would be specified somewhere if that was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise stipulated in your contract. The CAD40/hr is your gross rate, before taxes. You will need to file and pay your taxes (though many companies do withhold taxes for you).